# TypeError: Cannot read property 'xyz' of undefined although it is defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable called `cuisines` in my `component.ts` file which has been declared as follows:

component.ts

```
export class xyzComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route:Router,private activateRoute:ActivatedRoute,private http:HttpService) {

}

  cuisines:any = {};

ngOnInit() {

      this.activateRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {

        this.http.getResortByName(params.get('resort')).subscribe(dataRes => {
          console.log(params.get('resort'));
          this.resort = dataRes[0];
          Object.keys(this.resort.food).forEach(function(key){
              this.cuisines.push({name : key, cost: parseInt(this.resort.food[key]) });
          })

      })
    })

  }
```

When I try accessing `cuisines` from within `ngOnInit()` I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cuisines' of undefined
```

error. I tried a few things, but nothing seems to be working.

I moved the declaration of `cuisines` around, I removed the `this`, tried a few other things, but nothing is working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: change ``function(key)`` to ``(key) => `` . This is a scope issue

Comment: Hi @CruelEngine, thanks for your answer, I tried this, it says ````this.cuisines.push is not a function````

Comment: it is because ``cusines`` is not an array . You've declared it as an ``object`` . change ``cuisines : any = {}`` to ``cuisines : any = []``

Comment: @CruelEngine thank you, that helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by defining the following as an array.

```
public cuisines:any = [];
```

and then utilising the array function like so.

```
Object.keys(this.resort.food).forEach((key) => 
{
    this.cuisines.push({ name : key, cost: parseInt(this.resort.food[key])});
});
```

Comment: typo : ``.forEach((key) => {})``